# PHP command line string addition

Tags: php, sum, command-line-interface

Why does the inputs from the command line give me a sum of zero while adding inside the program gives me the result. My code is below :

```
echo "Enter the first number: ";
$num1 = trim(fgets(STDIN));
// echo $num1;
echo "Enter the second number: ";
$num2 = trim(fgets(STDIN));
// echo $num2;
$z= $num1 + $num2;  

$a = "2";
$b = "2";

echo "Sum of the numbers: ".$z." - ".($a+$b);
```

If i provide the input "2" for both the numbers from terminal the result is zero. The result would look like **Sum of the numbers: 0 - 4**, Why?

Comment: What exactly is `var_dump($num1)` giving you?

Comment: @deceze string(3) "2" and string(3) "2", i inputted  2 and 2

Comment: I test your code but it work.output `Sum of the numbers: 4 - 4`

Comment: My PHP version is PHP 7.0.23

Comment: "2" is not `(3)` characters long. You have some additional whitespace in there which you need to trim…

Comment: its coming as  string(3) ""2"" , any ideas?

Comment: Works fine in PHP 7.2

Answer (score 1):

i did copy paste, seems to work. 
but i think i know your problem, your input is "2" - is it with double quotes? 
 
when i put "2" i get the same result as you.
Now when you put "2" in the input, you actually get "\"2\"" in the code which is of course not a number, so trimming it might be your solution:

```
echo "Enter the first number: ";
$num1 = trim(fgets(STDIN), '"');
// echo $num1;
echo "Enter the second number: ";
$num2 = trim(fgets(STDIN), '"');
// echo $num2;
$z= $num1 + $num2;

$a = "2";
$b = "2";

echo "Sum of the numbers: ".$z." - ".($a+$b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a version problem. Works fine to me.. I am using php 7.1

[image]

Anyway, Try,

```
<?php
echo "Enter the first number: ";
$num1 = trim(fgets(STDIN));
// echo $num1;
echo "Enter the second number: ";
$num2 = trim(fgets(STDIN));
// echo $num2;
$z= (int) $num1 + (int) $num2;  

$a = 2;
$b = 2;

echo "Sum of the numbers: ".$z." - ".($a+$b); 
?>
```